# Why is background:url in CSS not working with Django?

Tags: css, django, url, background

I have the following CSS code for my navigation bar:

```
#footer-navigation {
  background: #1841c8 url('../images/nav_background.gif');
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
```

However, when I launch my local development server, it gives me the following even though the image exists in that location:

```
"GET /images/nav_background.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 1795
```

I am running Django 1.3.1, and I am using django.views.static.serve.

Comment: im pretty sure the image is not on /images/nav_background.gif then...

Comment: I missed that you were getting a 404 when you request the image. If you go to localhost:8000/images/nav_background.gif does the image show up?

Comment: I checked it and it doesn't show up.  It's a naming error.  The filename in the images folder had a "-" instead of a "_".

Answer (score 3):

```
"GET /images/nav_background.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 1795
```

The image you want to use is not found. I suggest you do follow these steps:

You can try these steps:

1. open your settings.py and

   - add this at the first line of your file:

     ```
     import os.path
     ```
   - change your STATIC_ROOT's value to:

     ```
     STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static/')
     ```
   - change your STATIC_URL's value to:

     ```
     STATIC_URL = '/static/'
     ```
2. create a folder named "static" in your project root.
3. create a folder for your static files like css, javascript and etc. I recommend you use a different folder for different types of files.
4. open the urls.py of your project

   - add this to your imports: import settings
   - add this to the url patterns:

     ```
     (r'(?:.*?/)?(?P<path>(css|jquery|jscripts|images)/.+)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT }),
     ```

   NOTE: In this example, there are folders named css, jquery, jscripts and images inside my static folder.
5. In your template add this:

for css files: (in this example, default.css is the name of the css file)

```
<link href="/{{ STATIC_ROOT }}css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

for javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/{{ STATIC_ROOT }}jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```

then change your code to this:

```
#footer-navigation {
background: #1841c8 url(images/nav_background.gif);
height: 40px;
padding: 0 0 0 20px;
                   }
```

Comment: Note that in Django11, point 4 will not work, as `'django.views.static.serve'` is not allowed. Instead do: `from django import views as django_views` and `url(r'(?:.*?/)?(?P<path>(css|jquery|jscripts|images)/.+)$', django_views.static.serve, {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT }),`

Answer (score 1):

try setting `MEDIA_ROOT` in your settings to where the image lives and then use

`{{ MEDIA_URL }}nav_background.gif`

EDIT:

Jakub Gocławski  is right.  It would appear your issue is that the image does not exist where you think it exists. If you're still having a problem let us know what you get when you visit localhost:8000/< the path to the image > .

Comment: I assume the question is about CSS file, not Django templates. `MEDIA_ROOT` won't work in a CSS file.