# Django css background-image

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

My css file is working but i can't add bacgorund image. I try 3 way but don't work.

This is my style.css

```
.first-info{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url( "{% static 'img/bg.jpg' %}");
}
```

This is my base.html ( img is working)

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}VPW{% endblock %}</title>



    <link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script href="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row head">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 logo">
                <img src="{% static 'img/logo1.png' %}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my main.html where i have class first-info.

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}VPW{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row first-info">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="box">
                Lorem Ipsum 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="box">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="box">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

I try change in css background-image: url( "{% static 'img/bg.jpg' %}"); to background-image: url( "img/bg.jpg"); but don't work it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is background:url in CSS not working with Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023282/why-is-backgroundurl-in-css-not-working-with-django)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour.  Django templating engine populates all the variables while rendering the html template. It will not populate values in your css file which is included in your html.

Your base.html because `{% static 'img/logo1.png' %}` is replaced into something like `/static/img/logo1.png` and browser is able to find the image, loads it and renders it.

If you want to make your background-image dynamic you can either .

You can add css class either directly in template i.e.

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}VPW{% endblock %}
 <style>
.first-info{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url( "{% static 'img/bg.jpg' %}");
}
</style>
{% block content %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row first-info">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="box">
                Lorem Ipsum 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="box">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="box">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Or use a inline css directly in your html tag.

```
<div class="row first-info" style="background-image: url({% static 'img/bg.jpg' %})" >
```

Or 
Just hardcode the complete path in your css file. But it removes the dynamic behaviour i.e. your static path. I am assuming it is just `/static/`

```
.first-info{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url( '/static/img/bg.jpg' );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

background-image:url('{{ STATIC_URL }}/img/bg.jpg');

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but I wanted to share this with someone trying to dynamically load a background image. My example is rendering a database request generated in views.py. The request contains three elements: background.photo, background.title and background.body.
Although not necessary, I wanted to apply opacity to the photo; however, using opacity property applies the effect to all children of the element in the DOM, so I used rgba to isolate the effect to the photo. The text is overlaid without being affected by the opacity of the photo. To make the text stand out, I used a horizontal gradient to darken the photo on the left.

```
    {% extends 'base_layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="background-image" style="background: url({{ background.photo.url }} ) no-repeat; background-size: 100%;">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="title-text">{{ background.title }}</h2>
        <p class="body-text">{{ background.body }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And the css:

```
.container{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(255,255,255,0));
}

.background-image{
    margin: 1em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #ff0080;
}

.title-text{
    font-family: serif;
    color: #ff0080;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .5em 1em;
}

.body-text{
    font-family: serif;
    color: #ff0080;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1.5em 4em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This just worked for me:

```
<style="background-image: url({% static 'images/cover.jpg' %})">
```

Source:
https://simpleit.rocks/python/django/call-static-templatetag-for-background-image-in-css/

Comment: this also worked for me after so many days of searching.

Answer (score 1):

```
.bgded{
      background-image: url( "{% static 'images/ur.jpg' %}");
  }
  .wrapper {
  display: grid;
}
```

Add this

Answer (score 0):

Django is not processing .css file includes just renders html templates.

Your CSS is static file and url should there be included through processing of some kind of management command if you want it to be extensible.

Othewise just use path of url

Comment: Can you explain it to me more

Comment: For instance https://github.com/andreyfedoseev/django-static-precompiler

Answer (score 0):

Just replace in static with `'..'`.
It will solve:

```
background:url('../images/Course.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Images must be in `static/app/images/` and .css files must be located in `static/app/content/`.

Further in the .css file write like this:

```css
#home {
  background: url(../images/1.jpg);
}
```